# PostCSS syntax in WebStorm

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm, postcss

I'd like to start use PostCSS plugins in WebStorm and I want to know how to do it.

I've created the new project with `index.html` & `style.css`. For the last I set PostCSS dialect. PostCSS plugin installed automatically.

I write

```
main{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  section{
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

and postcss-nest doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Screenshots please. https://postimg.org/image/fu1odon79/ (PhpStorm and `.pcss` file but still)

Comment: can't see any issues when using your syntax - it's highlighted correctly if postcss dialect is being used

Answer (score 18):

You can enable PostCSS support for your .css files in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Stylesheets | Dialects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this should be marked as accepted answer!

Comment: THANK YOU, i have been fighting this for hours now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wasted tons of time on this. My Workaround was to use the less syntax, which was not exactly what I was looking for. But this is the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment, not enough reputation. Are you using `postcss-cli`, the WebStorm PostCSS support plugin, or a build tool (and if so, which one)?

Comment: WebStorm PostCSS support plugin

Comment: @MaximYazykov Can you make sure it is not a problem with setting the dialect? Does it work when you change the file extension to `.pcss`?

Comment: doesn't work. Can you tell me step by step what shall I do (after creating new project with index.html)?

Comment: @MaximYazykov Make a new file called style.pcss and add the code from your question

Comment: @MaximYazykov See LazyOnes comment. Do you expect the code to compile to css? Because if I understood that correctly that is not what the WebStorm PostCSS plugin does. It just gives you autocomplete, syntax highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install postcss-nested . Then you should make a configuration.  I am using postCSS in my vue projects and this is my solution for myself.

1. npm install postcss-nested@4.2.3
2. create a postcss.config.js file in your main directory and add these lines.

> ```
> module.exports = {
> plugins: {'postcss-nested': {}}
> }
> ```

it should work clearly.

```
.main{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  &-section{
      width: 60%;
      height: 50px;
      border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```